# What is a "PR"? What does PR stand for in the context of FreeBSD Ports

Tags: port, freebsd

Compare:

- http://www.freebsd.org/prstats/index.html

A specific "PR":

- http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=134774

Does it stand for Portability Report? or something similar? I can tell it has to do with tracking bug reports and build problems for specific ports but the acronym is baffling me.

It may also be used in the Linux world but Googling for "Linux PR" only yields results related to Public Relations. Apparently FreeBSD has PRs and Linux has Public Relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To FreeBSD a PR is a "ticket" containing either (or both) a bug report or a feature request or a patch (to be thoughtfully tried and eventually committed by someone with the proper permissions).

It's used to track problems and their resolution ("closing" a PR usually means the underlying problem was solved).

Comment: BTW: a PR is not specific to the context of FreeBSD Ports, but FreeBSD in general; "ports" is just one of the many categories a PR can have.

Answer (score 6):

"Problem Reports".

I found a link:

- http://portsmon.freebsd.org/

Answer (score 5):

A PR is a Problem Report. It's not only used for problems but as a way to track any user-submitted issues including bugs, ideas and patches related to the base system (src) and ports.

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/pr-guidelines/article.html explains all about PRs in FreeBSD.